# Importing tablespace blocked by active index creation?

Tags: mysql

While attempting to import tablespace (mytable) to a second catalog (stage1) it seems the engine is blocking the process because I'm also trying to add an index to a very large table (700G) on another catalog (mydb.largetable).

Once I paused the index creation, the alter table to import the tablespace executed in seconds.

DB: mysql 5.6

Index add - PTOSC

I cannot seem to find any documentation about why this occurs.

Comment: i'd investigate by `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to see what the session is waiting on; i suspect it's a metadata lock,  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/metadata-locking.html   but i'm very curious about how you "paused the index creation", what statements are issued to pause and resume an operation like that.  I can understand cancelling an operation  would cause locks to be released. But the usage of "paused" in this context seems to indicate that the operation wasn't cancelled.

Comment: Nothing was on metadata lock, that's where I'm confused.

PTOSC allows users to pause an index creation manually or to cancel it all together if the running thread exceed a threshold.

Comment: Is it commonly understood that PTOSC refers to Percona **pt-online-schema-change** tool? There is a tag on StackOverflow for that `pt-online-schema-change`. Seems like the question being asked here might be "what locks obtained and held by pt-online-schema-change conflict with an import of InnoDB transportable tablespace?"